# How to change the marketplace repository I'm using? through public and private passwords

Tags: magento2, installation, marketplace

I recently started the development of a magento 2 store, and I used my marketplace account to use composer install during the magento installation, but we purchased some modules using another marketplace account and we need to change this information from where it pulls the repository. How can I change this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have in your root a `auth.json`file where you can specify all the keys you need ; ex

```
{
    "http-basic": {
        "repo.magento.com": {
            "username": "xxx0",
            "password": "yyy0"
        },
        "composer.amasty.com": {
            "username": "xxx1",
            "password": "yyy1"
        }
    }
}
```